# matlab метод Эйлера для решения диф уравнения

Tags: matlab, численные-методы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Реализовал метод Эйлера, который работает для дифференциального уравнения номер 1, а для второго выдает ошибку, помогите, пожалуйста!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
clear all
clc

 fun='t.^2*cos(t)+2/t';

fun=inline(fun);
t(1)=0.1;
h=0.03;
for i=1:50;
    
t(i+1)=t(i)+h*fun(t(i));
if t(i+1)-t(i)<0.01
break
end
i=i+1;
end
plot(t)
grid on;[![для этого уравнения все работает][1]][1]
```

Пытаюсь сделать для уравнения номер 2 и выдает ошибку:

> ```
> Error using inline/subsref (line 12)
> Not enough inputs to inline function.
> ?
> Error in LR_1_1 (line 11)
> t(i+1)=t(i)+h*fun(t(i));
> ```

при запуске следующего кода:

```
clear all
clc


fun = 't*sin(t)+sin(t)*cos(t)*exp.^(-cos(t))';
fun=inline(fun);
t(1)=0.1;
h=0.03;
for i=1:50;
 
t(i+1)=t(i)+h*fun(t(i));
if t(i+1)-t(i)<0.01
break
end
i=i+1;
end
plot(t)
grid on;
```

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка на самом деле здесь:

```
fun = 't*sin(t)+sin(t)*cos(t)*exp.^(-cos(t))';
```

Матлаб думает, что `exp` это имя аргумента, а не функции, и ждёт, что в `fun` будет передано 2 аргумента. Правильно так:

```
fun = 't*sin(t)+sin(t)*cos(t)*exp(-cos(t))';
```

А вообще объекты `inline` лучше не использовать, в том числе из-за возможности возникновения вот такой вот ситуации. Тем более, что им есть замена - анонимные функции.